# Extract identical color Foreground from Background of an image using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image which has an almost identical color foreground and background

[image: Input image],

I am trying to extract the foreground using the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Image dir
IMAGE_NAME = 'RGB_Test'

# Grab path to current working directory 
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd() 

# Path to image 
PATH_TO_IMAGE = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, IMAGE_NAME, 'RGB_test.JPG')

# Using cv2.imread() method 
img = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE) 

# convert to RGB
img_color = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Displaying the image 
plt.figure("Original")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.figure("RGB")
plt.imshow(img_color)
plt.figure("HSV")
plt.imshow(hsv)
plt.show()

# threshold
r1 = (10,25,130)
r2 = (25,150,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,r1,r2)

# apply morphology closing and opening to mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# make mask 3 channel
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# invert mask
mask_i = 255 - mask

# apply mask to input
img_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

# combine inverted mask with masked image
r = cv2.add(img_mask, mask_i)

# Displaying the image 
plt.figure("Mask")
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.figure("Mask Inv")
plt.imshow(mask_i)
plt.figure("Img_mask")
plt.imshow(img_mask)
plt.figure("Final Results")
plt.imshow(r)
plt.show()
```

I got the below image, where all the object did not mask properly, Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

[image: masked image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is virtually impossible by a mere colorimetric transformation. The vegetables and ground have about the same hue and saturation, and the dirty ones are color... ground.

From what I have seen, there is only sufficient contrast in the luminance or in the red component. This is what you get after binarization. I am afraid you can't do much better.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not impossible but you need to find lots of potato images and train using Mask-RCNN.

So far, the current Mask-RCNN is not trained using potato images therefore the result is not accurate:

[image]

But you can see that the network finds the single potato one-by-one. You need to feed more similar images into the network to get an accurate result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I am planning to get more images and apply Mask-RCNN